# Dynamic CRM trial login integration with .NET

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I need to create POC applicaiton which make API call to Dynamic CRM from .NET. For time being, I don't have CRM actual account, it will be avaibale after POC.

Can any one share me how it could possible ? it is possibel through trial login of CRM and that allow to create account ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First start a Dynamics CRM Online trial from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-free-trial-overview.aspx

After you download the latest CRM 2013 SDK from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40321

After you can use this code (simplified connection) to connect and create an account:

```cs
CrmConnection crmConnection = CrmConnection.Parse("Url=https://XXX.crm.dynamics.com; Username=user@domain.onmicrosoft.com; Password=passwordhere;");
OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(crmConnection);

Entity account = new Entity("account");
account["name"] = "Test Account";

Guid accountId = service.Create(account);
```

Refers to this msdn article for create the right connection string

[Simplified Connection to Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695810.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Guido gives an excellent starting point.  I'll just add a note about Early Bound Generation, since this is what the majority of are used to / want.  Guido's example code uses the Late Bound Entity class.  Use the [early bound generator](https://xrmearlyboundgenerator.codeplex.com/) to create typed entities based on your CRM customizations, and reference them in your project.  This would change Guido's code example to this:

```cs
CrmConnection crmConnection = CrmConnection.Parse("Url=https://XXX.crm.dynamics.com; Username=user@domain.onmicrosoft.com; Password=passwordhere;");
OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(crmConnection);

Account account = new Account{
    Name = "Test Account",
};
account.Id = service.Create(account);
```